# How can I make the data open in the same form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i want to transfer values from one form to another...

This is the code for the MainPage

```
    Public Property StringPass As String
    Public Property NumPass As String
    Private Sub MainPage_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Label7.Text = StringPass
    TextBox3.Text = NumPass

    End Sub
```

This is the code for the SecondPage

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Dim OBJ As New MainPage
  Dim NUM As New MainPage
  OBJ.StringPass = TextBox1.Text
  NUM.NumPass = TextBox6.Text
  OBJ.Show()
  NUM.Show()
  Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

How can OBJ and NUM pass values to their respective textboxes but open in the same MainPage?

Comment: This is not a vba question or a visual-studio question.  This is a vb.net question as best as I can tell

Comment: `OBJ.NumPass = TextBox6.Text` ?  Pretty unclear what you are asking for here.

Comment: `OBJ` and `NUM` (terrible, terrible naming BTW) are **two distinct instances** of the `MainPage` class. If you want one `MainPage` instance, then make *one* `MainPage` instance, not two. Your question is very unclear as it stands.

Comment: edited my question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating 2 forms and you only need one.
If you want to pass data to the next form you can assign those values just like you would with a normal class.

Make sure you have saved all forms as well.

> Your naming convention is not the best here just FYI.

Here is an example with your code.

This is the code for the SecondPage

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Dim OBJ As New MainPage
  OBJ.Label7.Text = TextBox1.Text
  OBJ.TextBox3.Text = TextBox6.Text
  OBJ.Show()
  Me.Hide()
End Sub
```